# Slow requests PAW REST client trial

Tags: paw-app

I am evaluating the PAW REST client trial and get extremely slow response time.

Same request with browser take about 150ms and 5-6 seconds with PAW.

Is that normal or have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, Paw is not currently optimized for time. The underlying HTTP client has been developed to allow debug features and its priority is not to be fast. That is said, we would like to improve that, and the 5-6 seconds range is not what to be expected at all! For endpoints taking normally 150 ms, Paw could go up to 600 ms but never seen slower... Maybe try to switch the HTTP Library in Preferences > HTTP.

Comment: Switching Library worked! :)

Another problem is that the autoexpanding response window animate very slow when changing size. My current os is Yosemite ..